# React native image not loading from server

Tags: php, android, imageview, react-native

Image from the server is not loading to the Imageview but it loads on a webview

the URL also loads on the browser.The code is as given below I also tried it with native android studio project still the image is not loading to the  imageview

```
  <Image
         source={{uri:BASEURL+
            "/images/cuisine/small/"+

            info.item.imagename}}

           style={styles.image}
         />
```

Answer (score 1):

I used the below code and got the image. Can you please comment your style.image? Then I can check.

```
export default class DisplayAnImage extends Component {   render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Image
          style={{width: 50, height: 50}}
          source={{uri: 'http://keralaculture.org/images/cuisine/thumb/vishu_katta_114.jpg'}}
        />
      </View>
    );   } }
```

Comment: I also had same issue. This solved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
<Image
     source={{uri: "" + BASEURL + 
                   "/images/cuisine/small/" + 
                   info.item.imagename + ""}}

       style={styles.image}
     />
```

hope it'll work for you....